# Why is my 3d-transformed div clipped, even though the parent element is set to overflow:visible?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a div inside another div for the sidebar of a website. I applied a transform to the inner div. The inner div is transformed as expected. However instead of sticking out of the outer div the inner div looks like the parent div has the `overflow: hidden` property applied and is clipped. Why is that?

**The Style:**

```
div#outer{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-perspective: 250px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div.inner {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(
      0.9109, 0, -0.103279, 0,·
      0, 1, 0, 0,·
      0.203279, 0, 0.2109, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="#outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Inner Div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser are we talking about? Have you tried it with several browsers to find out if it's a browser specific problem?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome. The example is shortened. I erased the moz-directives.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the **#** in front of the outer id value.

```
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Inner Div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not it. Error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Doh. Parent's parent has `overflow:hidden` set, that clips the element. Thanks for helping anyway!